# Fill in red boxes

Tags: super-mario-world

In Super Mario World, World 4 at the Star Road course, I'm unable to get to the key.
Here's an image of what I want it to look like, in fact the boxes are just empty dashed frames, but can't stand on them.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Super Mario World those dashed in boxes only appear after hitting the appropriately colored button of that color.

In this case you'll find that button here

Comment: Is the red button a toggle button after unlocking the switch palace?